# What is the technically correct way to achieve A/V sync in an MP4 file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, video-capture

I am working with a small header only mp4 library ([minimp4](https://github.com/lieff/minimp4)) to write mp4 files consisting of AAC audio and HVEC video streams, and using FFmpeg/ffplay/ffprobe to inspect and play them. I am a bit confused however, about mp4 concepts like decode/presentation/composition times and how I should be using those for sync.

Initially, I was writing all samples of audio and video as they came in, and using my expected duration as the duration. This obviously lead to a situation where I sometimes started getting video samples before audio causing the audio to run ahead of video. To correct this, I first attempted to manually set the "timestamp" parameter the library writes as well as use a real calculated duration. I realized this would not work in the mode I was using (non fragmented) and seemed to be an improper approach as the timestamp would be written as a decode timestamp (`tfdt`, not presentation), so instead I changed my writing functions to throw away any A/V samples that start before the other has some ready. This approach seems to work really well, although I am not sure how resilient it would be to drift over time.

After getting that to work and trying to look through FFmpeg source to see how they are handled, I noticed that ffprobe, at least, does use the decode timestamp as a presentation timestamp in some cases (`int64_t pts = pkt->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE ? pkt->pts : pkt->dts;`). I am also having trouble finding where a valid pkt->pts would come from at this point so it almost seems like the intended case.

Google lead me to the CTTS table/composition timestamp, but that seems to be more for reordering frames (not something I have to worry about as I am using all I-frames for video) so I am a bit at a loss/confused about what the technically proper, or at least most common/supported way of handling A/V sync in MP4 files is.